# ssh -x : howto get clipboard?

Tags: linux, ssh, clipboard

I'm connected to a server via ssh -x and my only way to get text out of the system is the x clipboard (unless i want to take thousends of screenshots and OCR over it).

I can not execute any programs on the other machine, because i don't have access.

How can I achive this?

Comment: Are you sure that scp and/or sftp is disabled?

Comment: I guess the only other way is not to use a clipboard but to `rsync` the file. I'm not pretending this is the ideal solution but neither are the other answers.

Answer (score 6):

Use xclip.

On the remote computer

```
xclip a_text_file_with_some_data.txt
```

On the local computer

```
xclip -o > test.txt
```

You did move the text via the clipboard, but not the "normal" way :)

Comment: my problem is that a propertiery "shell" (An X program) is my only way to access the data. I cannot execute other programs on the server. This "shell" stores data in the X clipboard. My problem is that i can't past it on my local Server. xclip -o test.txt outputs the clipboard of my own server.

Comment: Nice. It works with stdin/stdout too. So what I'd do remotely is `cat myfile.txt | xclip ` and locally on my Mac is `xclip -o | pbcopy`

Answer (score 0):

Many terminal emulators (PuTTY, gnome-terminal, Xterm) let you either:

- log all terminal output to a file, or
- set a *really* big scrollback buffer (01000 lines or so) and then copy all of it.

Comment: There is no output on the terminal i could copy. it is all inside an X-Window.